# Confused by the pseudo R2 for my zero-inflated regression

Tags: r, regression, r-squared, zero-inflation, pseudo-r-squared

#### Data

Here is the data I am using, which records my coffee consumption and productivity habits by day:

```
work <- structure(list(Coffee_Cups = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 
9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
0L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
9L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
NA, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L), Mins_Work = c(435L, 
350L, 145L, 135L, 15L, 60L, 60L, 390L, 395L, 395L, 315L, 80L, 
580L, 175L, 545L, 230L, 435L, 370L, 255L, 515L, 330L, 65L, 115L, 
550L, 420L, 45L, 266L, 196L, 198L, 220L, 17L, 382L, 0L, 180L, 
343L, 207L, 263L, 332L, 0L, 0L, 259L, 417L, 282L, 685L, 517L, 
111L, 64L, 466L, 499L, 460L, 269L, 300L, 427L, 301L, 436L, 342L, 
229L, 379L, 102L, 146L, NA, 94L, 345L, 73L, 204L, 512L, 113L, 
135L, 458L, 493L, 552L, 108L, 335L, 395L, 508L, 546L, 396L, 159L, 
325L, 747L, 650L, 377L, 461L, 669L, 186L, 220L, 410L, 708L, 409L, 
515L, 413L, 166L, 451L, 660L, 177L, 192L, 191L, 461L, 637L, 297L, 
601L, 586L, 270L, 479L, 0L, 480L, 397L, 174L, 111L, 0L, 610L, 
332L, 345L, 423L, 160L, 611L, 0L, 345L, 550L, 324L, 427L, 505L, 
632L, 560L, 230L, 495L, 235L, 522L, 654L, 465L, 377L, 260L, 572L, 
612L, 594L, 624L, 237L, 0L, 38L, 409L, 634L, 292L, 706L, 399L, 
568L, 0L, 694L, 298L, 616L, 553L, 581L, 423L, 636L, 623L, 338L, 
345L, 521L, 438L, 504L, 600L, 616L, 656L, 285L, 474L, 688L, 278L, 
383L, 535L, 363L, 470L, 457L, 303L, 123L, 363L, 329L, 513L, 636L, 
421L, 220L, 430L, 428L, 536L, 156L, 615L, 429L, 103L, 332L, 250L, 
281L, 248L, 435L, 589L, 515L, 158L, 0L, 649L, 427L, 193L, 225L, 
0L, 280L, 163L, 536L, 301L, 406L, 230L, 519L, 0L, 303L, 472L, 
392L, 326L, 368L, 405L, 515L, 308L, 259L, 769L, 93L, 517L, 261L, 
420L, 248L, 265L, 834L, 313L, 131L, 298L, 134L, 385L, 648L, 529L, 
487L, 533L, 641L, 429L, 339L, 508L, 560L, 439L, 381L, 397L, 692L, 
534L, 148L, 366L, 167L, 425L, 315L, 476L, 384L, 498L, 502L, 308L, 
360L, 203L, 410L, 626L, 593L, 409L, 531L, 157L, 0L, 357L, 443L, 
615L, 564L, 341L, 352L, 609L, 686L, 386L, 323L, 362L, 597L, 325L, 
51L, 570L, 579L, 284L, 0L, 530L, 171L, 640L, 263L, 112L, 217L, 
152L, 203L, 394L, 135L, 234L, 507L, 224L, 174L, 210L, 138L, 52L, 
326L, 413L, 695L, 370L, 256L, 327L, 490L, 128L, 469L, 567L, 359L, 
561L, 478L, 233L, 550L, 390L, 406L, 56L, 47L, 258L, 332L, 114L, 
193L, 435L, 493L, 659L, 93L, 86L, 0L, 228L, 232L, 318L, 295L, 
639L, 367L, 313L, 253L, 433L, 399L, 269L, 446L, 407L, 424L, 410L, 
309L, 364L, 700L, 345L, 274L, 113L, 202L, 553L, 157L, 351L, 303L, 
392L, 539L, 337L, 297L, 479L, 311L, 173L, 94L, 170L, 469L, 180L, 
311L, 106L, 521L, 378L, 61L, 462L, 644L, 310L, 533L, 517L, 136L, 
0L, 392L, 88L, 389L, 486L, 373L, 85L, 130L, 43L, 215L, 621L, 
337L, 471L, 574L, 33L, 610L, 415L, 362L, 410L, 376L, 226L, 360L, 
622L, 639L, 578L, 41L, 436L, 0L, 530L, 603L, 494L, 0L, 0L, 389L, 
159L, 0L, 346L, 469L, 568L, 374L, 408L, 187L, 0L, 546L, 433L, 
505L, 663L, 745L, 205L, 0L, 486L, 283L, 328L, 687L, 520L, 290L, 
285L, 447L, 568L)), row.names = c(NA, -434L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### Distribution and Normal Regression

Running a histogram of the data, I noticed to no surprise that there are several zero values. These are many days when I didn't work, which would be fairly common...

[image]

As this is the case, fitting a regression seems a bit odd. Running a simple linear regression as is like so:

```
reg.fit <- lm(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups, data = work)
summary(reg.fit)
```

...the fit is fairly poor for describing the effect, with a whopping .07 r-square value:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups, data = work)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-474.24 -139.31    2.05  134.33  455.52 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  266.384     18.004   14.80  < 2e-16 ***
Coffee_Cups   23.095      3.975    5.81 1.22e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 181.6 on 429 degrees of freedom
  (因为不存在，3个观察量被删除了)
Multiple R-squared:  0.07293,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.07077 
F-statistic: 33.75 on 1 and 429 DF,  p-value: 1.222e-08
```

A scatterplot shows the relationship. I've jittered the points because they cluster mostly around a finite number of values:

[image]

#### Zero Inflation Regression

Noticing this issue, I tried fitting a zero-inflated regression to see if it was more appropriate:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(pscl)
library(performance)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- zeroinfl(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups, 
                data = work)

#### Summarize Model ####
summary(fit)
model_performance(fit)
r2_zeroinflated(fit)
```

Observing the summary, I get this output:

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups, data = work)

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-8.04552 -1.74949  0.03907  1.76010  6.13010 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 5.708956   0.005552 1028.20   <2e-16 ***
Coffee_Cups 0.053355   0.001155   46.18   <2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -2.1378     0.3936  -5.432 5.59e-08 ***
Coffee_Cups  -0.2419     0.1090  -2.219   0.0265 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 1 
Log-likelihood: -1.9e+04 on 4 Df
```

#### Problem

The issue I'm having is that running the pseudo R2 that I have listed above gives me this:

```
# R2 for Zero-Inflated and Hurdle Regression
       R2: 0.998
  adj. R2: 0.998
```

This seems impossible. If the R2 here is correct, my model perfectly accounts for productivity, but that is obviously not true as some days when I drank coffee I would work a ton and others I would get basically nothing done regardless. Have I mis-specified the regression (the SE for the count model is extremely low) or is it the nature of my data that is causing this weird result?

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation for r2_zeroinflated is rather terse, and doesn't help me understand how it's being calculate (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/performance/performance.pdf). But maybe it's worth trying method="correlation" to see what that gives?

Comment: What is the equation for calculating the pseudo $R^2$ you want? I haven’t done this for a zero-inflated model like yours, but even for a logistic regression, there are [many options](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/). // To answer which formula you want, consider why you want an $R^2$-style statistic. This will help clarify what you seek (which might not be an $R^2$-style statistic at all).

Comment: I'm looking for something that captures explainable variation in responses similar to an OLS R2 value. I'm aware that there are many pseudo R2's out there for different purposes, which is part of why I was reticent about taking it at face value beyond the high value it kicked back.

Comment: @JohnMadden I just tried what you said and it gave me a value of 0.07259997 which seems a lot more believable.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but the source code of the r2_zeroinflated function being used to help facilitate discussion:

```
.r2_zi_default <- function(model) {
  n <- insight::n_obs(model)
  k <- length(insight::find_parameters(model)[["conditional"]])

  y <- insight::get_response(model, verbose = FALSE)
  # pred <- stats::predict(model, type = "response")

  var_fixed <- sum((stats::fitted(model) - mean(y))^2)
  var_resid <- sum(stats::residuals(model, type = "pearson")^2)

  r2_zi <- var_fixed / (var_resid + var_fixed)
  r2_zi_adj <- 1 - (1 - r2_zi) * (n - 1) / (n - k - 1)

  out <- list(R2 = r2_zi, R2_adjusted = r2_zi_adj)

  names(out$R2) <- "R2"
  names(out$R2_adjusted) <- "adjusted R2"

  attr(out, "model_type") <- "Zero-Inflated and Hurdle"
  structure(class = "r2_generic", out)
}
```

With option "method='correlation'" it instead runs this code:

```
.r2_zi_correlation <- function(model) {
  r2_zi <- stats::cor(
    insight::get_response(model, verbose = FALSE),
    stats::predict(model, type = "response")
  )^2 
  names(r2_zi) <- "R2 for ZI-models"
  r2_zi
}
```